# DownloadListener & contentLength

Tags: android, header-files, android-download-manager, content-length

Q is: why `long contentLength`
in:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength)
```

is equals '-1' when other arguments are proper?

If `Content-Length`on website is like:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
header('Content-Range: bytes 0-' . ($offset + $length) . '/' . $size);
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
header("Content-Type: ".$contentType);
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

so this should be in thousands, and it is only on server side. 
How can i solve this?

Comment: maybe is case sensitive. The l of  `Content-Length` is capital, not lowercase

Comment: it doesnt change anything, i've tried

Comment: are you sure $size is != -1 ?

Comment: yup i send $size as filename and it was like 187654

Comment: @Filip I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: @AbdelazizMirad sorry, i did not.